# Loop producing column mode instead of side by side

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to recreate this structure for wordpress posts so that post position them selfs on after other in three columns

correct html format

```
<div class="clearfix colelem" id="ppu6561"><!-- group -->
 <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu6561"><!-- group -->
  <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame clearfix grpelem" id="u6561" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><!-- image --><div id="u6561_clip"><img class="position_content" id="u6561_img" src="images/img_2454.jpg" alt="" width="288" height="216"/></div></a>
  <div class="rgba-background clearfix grpelem" id="u527"><!-- group -->
   <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u704-11"><!-- content -->
    <p id="u704-3"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704">50 CITIES CHALLENGE</span></a></p>
    <p id="u704-6"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704-4">FOLLOW MY ADVENTURES AS I VISIT</span></a></p>
    <p id="u704-9"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704-7">EVERY CITY IN ENGLAND</span></a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame clearfix grpelem" id="u7092" href="eurotrip.html"><!-- image --><div id="u7092_clip"><img class="position_content" id="u7092_img" src="images/social%20euro291x207.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="207"/></div></a>
 <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame clearfix grpelem" id="u6785" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/top-tips-for-overcoming-limiting-beliefs/"><!-- image --><div id="u6785_clip"><img class="position_content" id="u6785_img" src="images/limiting.jpg" alt="" width="346" height="207"/></div></a>
 <div class="rgba-background clearfix grpelem" id="u526"><!-- group -->
  <div class="pointer_cursor clearfix grpelem" id="u703-9"><!-- content -->
   <a class="block" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/top-tips-for-overcoming-limiting-beliefs/"></a>
   <h1 class="H1" id="u703-3"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/top-tips-for-overcoming-limiting-beliefs/"><span id="u703">OVERCOME LIMITING BELIEFS</span></a></h1>
   <p id="u703-5"><span id="u703-4">WHAT ARE LIMITING BELIEFS? AND WHY</span></p>
   <p id="u703-7"><span id="u703-6">&nbsp;THEY'RE HOLDING YOU BACK</span></p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="rgba-background clearfix grpelem" id="u530"><!-- group -->
  <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u705-11"><!-- content -->
   <p id="u705-3"><a class="nonblock" href="eurotrip.html"><span id="u705">EUROTRIP</span></a></p>
   <p id="u705-6"><a class="nonblock" href="eurotrip.html"><span id="u705-4">10 DAY TRAVELLING MASTERCLASS FOR</span></a></p>
   <p id="u705-9"><a class="nonblock" href="eurotrip.html"><span id="u705-7">&nbsp;SOCIAL SKILLS AND RELATIONSHIPS</span></a></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But the php I have seems to be not doing it right and forcing it to go into  a column mode for some reason

```
  <?php query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>

    <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>

        <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post();$i++;  ?>


      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="ppu6561"><!-- group --> 
     <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu6561"><!-- group -->
      <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame clearfix grpelem" id="u6561" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><!-- image --><div id="u6561_clip">  <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(400,400) ); ?> </div></a>
      <div class="rgba-background clearfix grpelem" id="u527"><!-- group -->
       <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u704-11"><!-- content -->

        <p id="u704-3"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></p>
        <p id="u704-6"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704-4"><?php printf("%s",$postsubtext);?></span></a></p>
        <p id="u704-9"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704-7">EVERY CITY IN ENGLAND</span></a></p>
       </div>


 </div>
 <?php  
     if($i % 2 == 0) {echo '</div>';} 
     ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>   

    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This is the html being produced by the query above

```
        <div class="clearfix colelem" id="ppu6561"><!-- group -->
       <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu6561"><!-- group -->
         <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame clearfix grpelem" id="u6561" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><!-- image --><div id="u6561_clip">  <img width="346" height="206" src="http://localhost:1337/globalgames/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/limiting.jpg" class="attachment-400x400 wp-post-image" alt="limiting" /> </div></a>
        <div class="rgba-background clearfix grpelem" id="u527"><!-- group -->
         <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u704-11"><!-- content -->

          <p id="u704-3"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704">50 CITIES CHALLENGE</span></a></p>
          <p id="u704-6"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704-4"></span></a></p>
          <p id="u704-9"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704-7">EVERY CITY IN ENGLAND</span></a></p>
       </div>


      </div>
      </div>


      <div class="clearfix colelem" id="ppu6561"><!-- group -->
     <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="pu6561"><!-- group -->
      <a class="nonblock nontext clip_frame clearfix grpelem" id="u6561" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><!-- image --><div id="u6561_clip">  <img width="288" height="216" src="http://localhost:1337/globalgames/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/img_2454.jpg" class="attachment-400x400 wp-post-image" alt="img_2454" /> </div></a>
      <div class="rgba-background clearfix grpelem" id="u527"><!-- group -->
       <div class="clearfix grpelem" id="u704-11"><!-- content -->

        <p id="u704-3"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704">Hello world!</span></a></p>
        <p id="u704-6"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704-4"></span></a></p>
        <p id="u704-9"><a class="nonblock" href="http://www.socialartist.co.uk/blog/category/50-cities-challenge/"><span id="u704-7">EVERY CITY IN ENGLAND</span></a></p>
       </div>


 </div>
```

Comment: In your correct HTML format codes, can you indicate the begining and end of a post scope? May be like `<!--post-->` and `<!--/post-->`. For me, it is little bit unclear how the posts are separating.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question:
"Loop producing column mode instead of side by side"

Column = side by side..
Instead = NOT

I could not get it. So are they on top of each other instead of side by side?

It would be much more helpful if you provide some active link for checking.